# Hotel name autocompleter contains html encoded entities using jquery and html

Tags: jquery, html

I have been stuck with this error.
"`King & Grove Hotel`" appears as "`King &amp; Grove Hotel`"

using jquery autocompletion.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My guess would be double-encoding. Somewhere along the way the final text being added to the autocomplete is likely: `&amp;amp;` Hard to suggest how/where to fix it w/o code.

Comment: Are you getting the value from a field? Have you tried to get using `.text` instead of `.html` ? Whats the question?

Comment: Yes I'm getting value from the field.

Comment: Here is the snippet of my question
When I give Kin( the autocompletion is for 3 letters) without a space- the jquery completion is the following
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span class="highlight">King</span> &amp; New York, New York, United States</a></li>

But when I search with MyH (and a space), here is the jquery element formed
<a id="ui-id-12" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><span class="highlight">King</span><span class="highlight"></span> <span class="highlight"></span>&amp;<span class="highlight"></span>

Comment: Hi Adam,

I have problems when the list populated in the jquery has an ampersand  and when I hit King(with a space) , the whole string has &amp;
Here is my regex for it 
 var regex = new RegExp("("+val.replace("&amp;", "&").replace(sanitization_regex, '\\$&').replace(/\s&/g, "&").replace(/\s+/g, "|") +")", "ig");

Answer (score 0):

To use ampersands and some other special characters in HTML you need to use the character codes. The code for an ampersand is:
`&#038;`

Replace the & with `&#038;` and it should work. Good luck.

Comment: Here is my reg expression var regex = new RegExp("("+val.replace(sanitization_regex, '\\$&').replace(/\s&+/g, "&").replace(/\s+/g, "|") +")", "ig"); //REgex- debugger // debugger; $('.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a').each(function() { //autocomplete debugger; // debugger; $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>")); }); So when the hotel name contains &, and when I type King with a space , & is getting converted into &amps;

Comment: Is there a way to handle space and & ? to get that off?
Please help me with that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app is probably storing the data in your database (whatever that is) properly as an HTML entity (&amp;), however upon retrieval your app is expecting the data to be parsed as HTML which would display an &amp; as an ampersand. jQuery is not doing that.

You should decode the data before showing it on the screen somehow. One option is to use http://underscorejs.org/ as follows:

```
_.escape(string)
```

or in this case:

```
_.unescape(string)
```

Comment: Here is my reg expression
    var regex = new RegExp("("+val.replace(sanitization_regex, '\\$&').replace(/\s&+/g, "&").replace(/\s+/g, "|") +")", "ig");
                //REgex- debugger
               // debugger;
                $('.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a').each(function() {
                    //autocomplete debugger;
                 //   debugger;
                    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>"));
                });

So when the hotel name contains &, and when I type King with a space , & is getting converted into &amps;

Comment: Ok, without seeing all your code, I'm going to suggest you not use regular expressions for something as simple as replacing an "&amp;" with a "&"... you could use a basic replace:  
  
**$(this).html($(this).html().replace("&amp;", "&");**  
  
followed by another replace for your *<span class='highlight'>*

no?

Comment: It still doesn't work :(.
The first one takes care of all the other expressions. I did add your suggestion to it , but looks like it doesn't work.
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>"));
$(this).html($(this).html().replace("&amp;", "&","<span class='highlight'>$1</span>"));
Am I doing anything wrong?

My reg expressions
sanitization_regex = new RegExp('[-/\\^$*+?.()&|[\\]{}]', 'g');
var regex = new RegExp("("+val.replace(sanitization_regex, '\\$&').replace(/\s&/g, "&").replace(/\s+/g, "|") +")", "ig");

Comment: take the user input and create a regex out of it
1) /[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g will escape any regex-special characters the user might have put in their string
2) \s+ will replace one or more spaces with a pipe, this means each word in the user's query will get matched against the list items separately. ie "york new city" will highlight any instance of "york", "new", and "city"
3) the 2nd param, "ig" means the search will be case insensitive and global (will match more than once)

Answer (score 0):

Here was the fix and that worked fine.
 $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&/,"&").replace(regex, "$1"));

First replace the & and then use that regex for other strings.

Comment: $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&amp;/,"&").replace(regex, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>"));